# Send with multiple CSVs using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have an app that takes in some information, performs some calculations using pandas, and turns the final pandas data frame into a CSV that is then downloaded using the Flask app. How do I download multiple CSVs within one view? It seems that I can only return a single response at a time.

An example snippet:

```
def serve_csv(dataframe,filename):
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(buffer, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(buffer,
             attachment_filename=filename,
             mimetype='text/csv')

def make_calculation(arg1, arg2):
   '''Does some calculations.
   input: arg1 - string, arg2- string
   returns: a pandas data frame'''

@app.route('test_app', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_app():
    form = Form1()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    calculated_dataframe = make_calculation(str(form.input_1.data), str(form.input_2.data))
        return serve_csv(calculated_dataframe, 'Your_final_output.csv')
    return render_template('test_app.html', form=form)
```

So let's say in that example above that `make_calculation` returned two pandas data frames. How would I print both of them to a CSV?

Comment: you could let the user download them as a zip?

Comment: It isn't possible to somehow respond to a request by offering multiple file downloads--one request, one response.  You could bundle the files in a zip, or instead return a web page with download links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could return a [MIME Multipart](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.txt) response, a zip file, or a TAR ball (please note the linked RFC is somewhat out of date, but is easier to quickly get up to speed with because it's in HTML; the official one is [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.txt)).

If you choose to do a MIME multipart response, a good starting point might be to look at the [`MultipartEncoder`](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py) and [`MultipartDecoder`](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/multipart/decoder.py) in [requests toolbelt](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/); you may be able to use them directly, or at least subclass/compose using those to get your desired behavior. [Zip files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and [TAR balls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) can be implemented using standard library modules.

An alternative would be to design your API so that you were returning JSON, use a header (or XML element or JSON field) to indicate that additional CSVs could be obtained by another request, or similar.

Answer (score 16):

This is **all the code** you need using the [`Zip files`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). It will return a zip file with all of your files.

In my program everything I want to zip is in an `output` folder so i just use `os.walk` and put it in the zip file with `write`. Before returning the `file` you need to **close** it, if you don't **close** it will return an empty file.

```
import zipfile
import os
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/download_all')
def download_all():
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Name.zip','w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root,dirs, files in os.walk('output/'):
        for file in files:
            zipf.write('output/'+file)
    zipf.close()
    return send_file('Name.zip',
            mimetype = 'zip',
            attachment_filename= 'Name.zip',
            as_attachment = True)
```

In the `html` I simply call the route:

```
<a href="{{url_for( 'download_all')}}"> DOWNLOAD ALL </a>
```

I hope this helped somebody. :)

Comment: I'd rather use a context manager, to avoid the close thing: `with Zipfile(...) as zf: zf.write(...)`. It's cleaner and safer in case of unexpected exceptions. Also, you can use `os.listdir()` instead of `os.walk()`.

Comment: Also you can use `os.path.join('output', file)` instead of `'output/' + file`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @desfido's answer above, here would be some code implementation that does not involve using zip, and instead downloads two different files:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

def make_calculation(arg1, arg2):
    '''Does some calculations.
    input: arg1 - string, arg2- string
    puts results in two different dataframes
    and stores them in two different files,
    returns the names of those two files'''
    return filename1, filename2

@app.route('test_app', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_app():
    form = Form1()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f1, f2 = make_calculation(str(form.input_1.data), str(form.input_2.data))
        m = MultipartEncoder({
           'field1': (f1, open(f1, 'rb'), 'text/plain'),
           'field2': (f2, open(f2, 'rb'), 'text/plain')
        })
        return Response(m.to_string(), mimetype=m.content_type)
   return render_template('test_app.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Using this method for me produces a single file with no extension and contents from all of the individual files' data, separated by the content-disposition & content-type of each csv file. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try this, using zip module --

```
import zipfile
from os.path import basename

UPLOAD_PATH = <upload_location>
base_files = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]
  
with zipfile.ZipFile(UPLOAD_PATH + 'Test.zip', 'w') as zipF:
    for file in base_files:
        zipF.write(UPLOAD_PATH + file, basename(UPLOAD_PATH + file), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipF.close()
return send_file(METAFILE_UPLOADS+'Test.zip', mimetype='zip', attachment_filename='Test.zip', as_attachment=True)
```