# Send multiple files with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sendfile

I have this code for sending a single file to the user side:

Server side:

```
@app.route('/image', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def image():
    # CU.close()
    SqlPicPlace="SELECT ImgData  FROM  tablename WHERE ImgSaveID=2"
    CU.execute(SqlPicPlace)
    ans=CU.fetchone()
    imgBinary = ans[0]    
    return send_file(io.BytesIO(imgBinary), attachment_filename='a.jpg', mimetype='image/jpg', as_attachment=True)
```

But I want to send more than 1 file to the user side. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download multiple CSVs using Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568687/download-multiple-csvs-using-flask)

Comment: That flask code is your client side? Are you sure that it's not your server-side?

Comment: @MichaelM. yes I type wrong and I edit that

Answer (score 2):

HTTP does not support this functionality, but you can zip your files into an archive and send it to a user.

Comment: what about a file along with a json?