# Flask download file not being presented

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to create a zip file on the fly, send the file to the user and remove the file from the server again, so far I've come up with the following:

```
@app.route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def download():
    shutil.make_archive('files', 'zip', dir_path+'/FILES')
    while not os.path.exists(dir_path+"/files.zip"):
        time.sleep(1)

    file_path = dir_path + "/files.zip"
    
    cache = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fp, cache)
        cache.flush()
    cache.seek(0)
    os.remove(file_path)
    return send_file(cache, as_attachment=True, mimetype='application/zip', download_name='data.zip')
```

Everything is working fine, even the response is code 200, except I never get prompted to download the file.

Still running the built-in Flask development server.

Am I just missing something? Maybe something small like a method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading multiple files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881709/downloading-multiple-files-in-flask)

Comment: @Detlef tried utilizing zipfile before, does not solve the issue either sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I also tried a variant of your code and didn't run into any errors. The file will be completely downloaded as soon as the URL is accessed.

Is it possible that your unnecessary loop for waiting for the created archive points to a path that doesn't exist?

This is the code I used. The files to be downloaded are in my [instance folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/).

```py
from flask import send_file
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os, shutil

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    path = shutil.make_archive(
        os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'files'), 'zip', 
        app.instance_path, 'FILES'
    )

    cache = NamedTemporaryFile()
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fp, cache)
        fp.flush()
    cache.seek(0)

    os.remove(path)

    return send_file(cache, 
        as_attachment=True, 
        download_name='archive.zip'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, apparently is was completely unrelated to the function, handled the response wrong when calling the function through JS, resolved by calling the function directly through Flask.